# calling super method from unrelated method

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, super

Today I realized that calling `super.foo()` is possible not only inside an overriding `foo` method, but also inside completely unrelated methods:

```
class Base
{
    void foo()
    {
    }
}

class Derived extends Base
{
    void foo()
    {
    }

    void bar()
    {
        super.foo();    
    }
}
```

Is there any real-world scenario, Design Pattern or whatever where this is actually useful?

Comment: You mean where you want to mix `foo` and `super.foo`? Cause otherwise you should do super in foo, and then just call `foo`. Too much foo in this comment? Possibly.

Comment: Sometimes you just don't like how you implemented foo but you do like how your parent did it.

Comment: @LoganMurphy I am looking for specific, concrete, real-world scenarios.

Comment: I don't know...something like this http://pastebin.com/G4CBpgD6 ...jsut because java has it does not mean it is useful... java hardly uses enums too.

Comment: Yeah it's a little bit of an obscure feature but there is no reason why it shouldn't be there. There might be a few corner cases where that's actually useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be helpful when a child class wants to provide more meaningful names to a method than the parent class, or providing additional information about the operation in the method name.